# Centos: Apache needs to read files created by Tomcat

Tags: permissions, centos, chmod, chown

After trying a lot of different solutions I came here for some help.

I have a web apps in apache HTTPD which serve the frontend and a Java app in Tomcat in the same server.

The thing is that the files created by Tomcat are not readable by Apache. I mean, the users can upload files in the appache server, it send the files to the Tomcat serve who process some information and storage the files in a public folder so Apache can read it. The thing is that Apache gets 403 on those files.

If I run chmod -R 777 in the img/ directory (where the files are storage) I get access to those files, but every time I upload a new file, the HTTPD doesn't have access to it until I run the command.

I created a group call webusers and I added the tomcat and apache users to it.

If I run ln -l over that directory I get (for the old files)

```
drwsrwsrwx. 2 tomcat webusers 4096 Aug 16 08:50 337
```

But when I upload a new file I get:

```
drwxr-s---. 2 tomcat webusers 4096 Aug 16 14:44 33f
```

And If I try to open in the browser I get

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /assets/img/cars/brands/33f1d3f1-0e4b-4924-acc1-11e28bed08a8/c_h_1.jpg on this server.

I tried many chown -R / chmod -R 7777 without success, could you help me to make readable by apache the files created by tomcat?

Comment: Is Apache being used for anything else?

Comment: No...Just to serve this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache is only used as a front for Tomcat, the simplest answer would be to have the Apache child processes run as Tomcat.  I'm not positive of your CentOS version but looking at a few things it looks like the default Apache2 package would create a config file in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.  From there you want to find the configuration parameter `User`.  In my environment I have something like:

```
User www-user
Group www
```

But it's likely your setup will be different.  Change the `User` to your Tomcat user and the `Group` to the same group that the Tomcat user has.  Again, I'm not positive of the location of the Apache configuration file - you may have to search a bit for that.  Once you've changed this setting you must restart Apache for it to take effect.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! this solve the issue... I change apache user for tomcat and the webusers group.. I'm not sure if this is the best answer because I do not prefer the idea of changing the users, but I run out of options.. I have the same situation in the past and I could make it works (I don;t remember how) So given the current scenario, this fixed my issue! So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are are using Java to upload files.

```
File f = new File("/path/to/image/image_name.jpg);
f.setExecutable(true, false);
f.setWritable(true, false);
f.setReadable(true, false);
```

Now you can access your files both from apache and tomcat.